# Disable TLS below version TLSv1.2 everywhere in infrastructure

Tags: ssl, db2, websphere, db2-luw

In the infrastructure we've got following machines:
1. Websphere application server (on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4)
2. DB2 server (on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4)

Customer wants to deactivate the TLS 1.1 and below everywhere within the infrastructure.
I know where to disable it in WAS Admin console on server 1, but I don't know where to disable it in other places. Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a programming question. This question asks about  Administration and configuration of WAS, and Db2-server etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Db2 instance configuration parameter `ssl_versions` to `TLSv12`. For example, when using the command line processor, while logged in as the instance owner:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using ssl_versions TLSv12
```

You will need to restart the instance for the change to take effect.

[Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0053616.html)